# How can I destroy data on a hard disk?

Tags: windows, security, data-recovery

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to secure delete file or folder in windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/86824/how-to-secure-delete-file-or-folder-in-windows)
>   [Erasing data before selling a computer](https://superuser.com/questions/4678/erasing-data-before-selling-a-computer)

I have a hard disk with some confidential data that I'm obliged to destroy. I've tried sweeping free hard disk spaace with CCleaner several times, but EasyRecovery can still read data without any problem.

Is there any way to *securely* wipe the data from hard disk (even the data that's already been overwritten by other files)?

Comment: see http://superuser.com/questions/4678/erasing-data-before-selling-a-computer

Answer (score 0):

To securely wipe a hard disk, open it up, remove the platters, incinerate them, and disperse the ash.

There's no way to wipe a hard disk that both allows it to be reused *and* gives 100% confidence that no data can be recovered from it.