# How can I make a video file unrecoverable?

Tags: file-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to secure delete file or folder in windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/86824/how-to-secure-delete-file-or-folder-in-windows)

I have very little computer skills but I have to remove some videos from a laptop that I already deleted and also deleted from the recycle bin.  Is there anything simple and undetectable I can do?

Answer (score 2):

Try using SDelete to wipe your free space. It's available here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897443.aspx

The command to use would be:

```
sdelete -z c:
```

Comment: FWIW, the same can be done with `cipher /w:C:\`, which comes as part of Windows.

Comment: Interesting, I never knew about that built-in functionality!

Comment: ...although I'm not sure whether `cipher` will wipe MFT entries too. (On the other hand, neither does `sdelete`.) So the file *name* may still remain on disk (although the *data* will be long gone). I used to like [Eraser](http://eraser.heidi.ie/) before the v6 full rewrite.